# Add system section from other extension

Tags: magento-1.8, system.xml

I developed a extension which has configuration options in the backend.

Is it possible to add another section to it from another extension?

[image]

This is the system.xml file from the first extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <newsletterpopup_config translate="label" module="fekete_newsletterpopup">
            <label>Fekete</label>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        </newsletterpopup_config>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <newsletterpopup_options translate="label" module="fekete_newsletterpopup">
            <label>Newsletter Popup</label>
            <tab>newsletterpopup_config</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <general translate="label">
                    <label>Allgemein</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <is_active translate="label comment">
                            <label>Aktiv</label>
                            <comment>Das Popup live schalten.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </is_active>
                        <type translate="label comment">
                            <label>Anzeigetyp</label>
                            <comment>Festlegen ob das Popup pro Sitzung angezeigt werden soll oder einmal und nie wieder.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                            <source_model>fekete_newsletterpopup/options</source_model>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </type>
                        <show_popup_to_guest translate="label comment">
                            <label>Popup auch Gästen zeigen</label>
                            <comment>Wenn Nein ausgewählt wurde, wird das PopUp nur angemeldeten Benutzern gezeigt.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </show_popup_to_guest>
                        <time_until_popup_shows translate="label comment">
                            <label>Zeit bis Popup erscheint</label>
                            <comment>Sekunden</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry validate-digits validate-digits-range digits-range-0.0-1000</validate>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </time_until_popup_shows>
                   </fields>
                </general>
                <content translate="label">
                    <label>Inhalt</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <header_title translate="label comment">
                            <label>Header Titel</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </header_title>
                        <content translate="label comment">
                            <label>Inhalt HTML</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </content>
                   </fields>
                </content>
                <appearance translate="label">
                    <label>Erscheinung</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <animation translate="label comment">
                            <label>Animations Effekt</label>
                            <comment>Animation</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                            <source_model>fekete_newsletterpopup/effects</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </animation>
                        <use_random_effect translate="label comment">
                            <label>Zufällige Animation</label>
                            <comment>Zufällige Animation verwenden?</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </use_random_effect> 
                        <header_background_color translate="label comment">
                            <label>Header Hintergrund Farbe</label>
                            <comment>Hex Code</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry color</validate>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </header_background_color> 
                        <header_text_color translate="label comment">
                            <label>Header Text Farbe</label>
                            <comment>Hex Code</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry color</validate>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </header_text_color> 
                   </fields>
                </appearance>
            </groups>
        </newsletterpopup_options>          
    </sections>
</config>
```

This is the system.xml from my new extension which should add a section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <fekete_switch_options translate="label" module="fekete_switch">
            <label>Switch</label>
            <tab>newsletterpopup_config</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <startseite translate="label">
                    <label>Startseite</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <is_active translate="label comment">
                            <label>Slider</label>
                            <comment>Slider auf der Startseite anzeigen.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </is_active>
                   </fields>
                </startseite>
            </groups>
        </fekete_switch_options>            
    </sections>
</config>
```

But I get a blank page, if I go to `System -> Configuration`.

Comment: Can you add the default system.xml to your question which is used by that module?

Comment: Change the sort order. Also delete the cache directory and try again

Comment: @SukumarGorai, Thats already all system.xml's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be with your **system.xml** file in **Fekete_Switch** module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <fekete_switch_options translate="label" module="fekete_switch">
```

here, you are using module as **fekete_switch** which is not correct and that is the reason you are getting a blank page.

Go to your **config.xml** file of your module **Fekete_Switch** and check for the tag name you have used for your helper.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Fekete_Switch>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Fekete_Switch>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <switch> <!-- Use this as your module name in system.xml file -->
        <class>Fekete_Switch_Helper</class>
      </switch>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

Use module as the helper tag e.g(**switch**) and your problem will most probably get resolved.

Don't forget to clear cache and logout and login to admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible without any issue.

As an example you can see `app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/etc/system.xml` which adds a Google Sitemap link to the catalog tab.

Here is part of the `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml` which defines the catalog tab and the Catalog section:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <catalog translate="label" module="catalog">
            <label>Catalog</label>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
        </catalog>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <catalog translate="label" module="catalog">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Catalog</label>
            <tab>catalog</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            ...
```

And here is part of the content of the `app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/etc/system.xml` which adds the `Google Sitemap` Section to the `Catalog` Tab which is defined in the above snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <sections>
        <sitemap translate="label" module="sitemap">
            <label>Google Sitemap</label>
            <tab>catalog</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>70</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            ...
```

It is possible your group or fields code is incorrect somewhere, so go through step by step making sure each step works before you continue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <fekete_switch_options>
            <label>Switch</label>
            <tab>newsletterpopup_config</tab>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <startseite translate="label">
                    <label>Startseite</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <is_active translate="label">
                            <label>Slider</label>
                            <comment>Slider auf der Startseite anzeigen.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </is_active>
                   </fields>
                </startseite>
            </groups>
        </fekete_switch_options>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**Note:** Clear all cache & logout you admin user & again login after check